# connect to kylin from R

Tags: r, kylin

I´m trying to access to Kylin cubes from my R code. My machine is Ubuntu server.
But I've been searching for packages or code to try it for long time to no avail.

What i've done so far after copied jar files to /usr/lib:

```
> drv <- JDBC("org.apache.kylin.jdbc.Driver",
+             "/usr/lib/kylin/kylin-jdbc-2.6.3.jar",
+             identifier.quote="`")

Error in .jfindClass(as.character(driverClass)[1]) : 
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.kylin.jdbc.Driver
```

any guidance would be much appreciated

Comment: maybe use `odbc`? see http://kylin.apache.org/docs/tutorial/odbc.html

Comment: Linux machine. any hint using jdbc?

Comment: Iirc there is also a jdbc under the tutorial page